# why does /bin/login fork on recent Linuxes

Tags: linux, shell, fork, exec

Back in the good old Unix days (as detailed by e.g. Stevens's Unix Network Programming, p.63, 1990), init forked, the child ran getty.  Then getty grabbed user name and exec'ed /bin/login, passing it the user name.  Then login asked for password, checked credentials, then exec'ed whatever was in /etc/passwd, normally a shell, e.g. /bin/bash.

The getty,login and shell all had same PID, due to the exec nature and lack of forks.

Now I see that /bin/login forks and runs the shell in the child, while the parent merely does a wait on the child.  At least this is the logic on Linux.  Why is this?  What purpose does it serve?  Who made this decision?? 
Can I spawn login to NOT use fork??

It's a pain, for me at least.  I'm building a pseudo terminal using forkpty and running login on the slave side.  I use the pid result of the forkpty to e.g. raise a signal in the child.  Of course what I want is the pid of bash, not of login.  Now that those pids are different, I have to chase down bash's pid, with a yucky 'ps -o pid= --ppid LOGINPID' run through popen.

Stuart

Answer (score 2):

According to https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/login.c#L1186 : "We must fork before setuid() because we need to call pam_close_session() as root." So it's due to [PAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module). The code is conditional on USE_PAM so I guess you could recompile shadow with PAM disabled at configuration time.